# ffmpeg make gif file size too big

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make gif from video by ffmpeg, but the output gif file size is too big.

`'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-ss' '00:00:00.00' '-t' '5' '-i' '/htdocs/vv.mp4' '-vf' 'scale=480:-1' '-gifflags' '+transdiff' '-y' '/htdocs/gg.gif'`

the input file size is just 259k, and the output file size is 1.7M.

Is there a simple way to lower down the gif size?

Comment: See method at https://superuser.com/a/556031/114058

Comment: You can try to optimize the gif, for example with lossygif (https://kornel.ski/lossygif), (you can play with it online at https://ezgif.com/optimize), it may reduce the file size of GIF generated from video somewhere around 40% depending on the settings and nature of image. But generally GIFs are almost always larger than MP4. GIF is an old and primitive image format, it was never intended for videos, so the compression is not optimal. Don't expect to get the same file size and quality.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem for so long. There are a few methods you can employ as a solution:

1. **Reduce Resolution**: You're already doing this by scaling the video. However, you can reduce the resolution even further if visual quality isn't a top priority.
2. **Optimize the Color Palette**: GIFs use a limited color palette (maximum of 256 colors). Instead of allowing `ffmpeg` to choose the palette, you can optimize it by first generating a palette from your video and then using that palette to create the GIF. Here's how:

   ```bash
   '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' -ss '00:00:00.00' -t '5' -i '/htdocs/vv.mp4' -vf "fps=10,scale=480:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" -y '/htdocs/palette.png'
   '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' -ss '00:00:00.00' -t '5' -i '/htdocs/vv.mp4' -i '/htdocs/palette.png' -lavfi "fps=10,scale=480:-1:flags=lanczos [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y '/htdocs/gg.gif'
   ```

   In the example above, the `fps=10` parameter sets the GIF to 10 frames per second, which is typically sufficient for GIFs and will help in reducing the size.

This method helped me a lot to reduce the gif size; I tried to use a significantly restricted color palette.

3. **Reduce Frame Rate**: As seen in the previous point, reducing the frames per second (fps) will reduce the number of frames in the GIF, subsequently reducing its size.

This method also helped me a lot. Although gifs weren't as usable as before, the size was my primary concern.

4. **Trim Unnecessary Sections**: You're already using the `-ss` and `-t` parameters to select a specific segment of the video. Ensure that you're trimming the video to only the most essential parts so you're not including any unnecessary frames.
5. **Use GIF Optimization Tools**: After you've created the GIF, you can use dedicated GIF optimization tools to further reduce its size. Tools like [Gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) can be particularly effective.

Also, I should mention that the nature of the GIF format means it's not particularly efficient at storing video data, so there are limits to how much you can compress it while retaining acceptable visual quality. Consider using video formats (e.g., WebM or MP4) for longer or high-quality animations, as they are typically more efficient than GIFs.